# How do I link images to drop down list values using arrays (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following task in front of me and I’ve been bumping my head against the wall in the last 5 days or so and just can’t seem to find the solution to it.

I want to create a plain html form with a drop down list with several options. To each of the options I would like to assign a specific image that would appear when the user clicks on a “select” button in the form.

My goal is to use arrays in javascript and somehow link the images to the options from the drop down list. Problem is – I don’t know how. Another issue in this case is that each image is stored on a different server so addressing the source is another problem for me.

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCShj.png)

When a user chooses an option and clicks on the “select” button a picture should appear on the page.

Thank you for your answers! 
I appreciate the help :)

Comment: Show here some code what you tried so far ?

Comment: Can you include `html`, `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you mean? You should use JavaScript for that first part of code is JavaScript code that adds to your HTML that functionality, below in comments I wrote a sort of instruction on how to include your JavaScipt code to your HTML file.

```js
var pic = document.getElementById('pic');
document.getElementById('select-image').addEventListener(
'change', function(e) {
  pic.src = this.value
})

//Include this code in your HTML file as follows:
//before </body> -body close tag include 
//<srcipt type="text/javascript">
//this whole code above goes here
//</script>
```

```html
<select id='select-image'>
  <option value="http://i.ndtvimg.com/i/2016-06/wolf_650x400_61465560359.jpg">wolf</option>
  <option value="http://www.picdesi.com/upload/comment/friend/best-friends-quote-pic.jpg">fingers</option>
  <option value="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/43547-A-True-Friend.jpg">list</option>
</select>
<img id="pic" src="" alt="">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- JavaScript code above comes here -->
</script>
```

**Update:**
As request in comments, insert web link of any picture in the input field and press enter, your picture gets attached to the select box, as you change options you see different images.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('photos-form'),
formName = document.getElementsByName('photos-form')[0],
select = formName.selectImage,
input = formName.store,
pic = document.getElementById('pic'),
arr = ["http://i.ndtvimg.com/i/2016-06/wolf_650x400_61465560359.jpg"];

form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    arr.push(input.value);
    input.value = ""
    for(var picture in arr) {
        if(!select.options[picture]) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.innerHTML = picture;
            option.value = arr[picture];
           select.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
    return false;
})

select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    pic.src = this.value
})
```

```html
<form id='photos-form' name="photos-form" action="" method="POST">
  <select name="selectImage" id='select-image'>
       <option value="http://i.ndtvimg.com/i/2016-06/wolf_650x400_61465560359.jpg">wolf</option>
    </select>
    <input id="store" name="store" type="text" />
</form>
<img id="pic" src="" alt="">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but for this project of mine I need to use arrays. I need to store the images in an array and then link them to the option from the drop down list. Would it be possible for you to give me a hint with the arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, using a single array, containing option id, text and url/path to image, it can easily be filled from a database using a for..loop and array.push({...}).

```js
var options = [ ];
  options.push( {id: 0, text: "..Please Select..", url: ""} );
  options.push( {id: 1, text: "Number One", url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG/275px-A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG"} );
  options.push( {id: 2, text: "Number Two", url:"http://sawadacoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/Sawada-Coffee-10DEC2015-003.jpg"} );
  options.push( {id: 3, text: "Number Three", url:"http://www.menshealth.com/sites/menshealth.com/files/coffee-mug.jpg"} );
  options.push( {id: 4, text: "Number Four", url:"http://www.seriouseats.com/images/2015/08/20150818-coffee-beans-shutterstock_71813833.jpg"} );
  options.push( {id: 5, text: "Number Five", url:"https://static1.squarespace.com/static/524b0cc5e4b052d320043cd2/t/5261693fe4b0c00e49809c00/1382115659249/coffee-cup.jpg?format=2500w"} );

for(var i = 0, length = options.length; i < length; i++){
  var opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.value = options[i].id;
      opt.text = options[i].text;
      dropdownTest.options.add(opt);
}

dropdownTest.onchange = function() {
    var elem = (typeof this.selectedIndex === "undefined" ? window.event.srcElement : this);
    var value = elem.value || elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
    imageTest.src = options[value].url;
};
```

```css
#imageTest {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdownTest"></select>
<br />
<image id="imageTest"></image>
```

Comment: Why do you make it that complicated?

Comment: @developer complicated? it's very basic.. i use array and build the options & image source as i expect he is storing it in a database, etc, needs to be able to edit it without having to edit html code... this is 2016, almost 17, afterall.

Comment: I  don't think he will understand something from what you've written as he is newbie, you've done it through algorithms, I know that its almost 2017, so to use 80s way where people weren't coding accurately